# Destructing function parameters with defaults. Does Babeljs support "nested" defaults?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I think I'm having a hard time explaining exactly what isn't working for me. Essentially I have this function:

```
createBalance(
{
    ColumnData: [, {value: debit=0} = {}, {value: credit=0} = {}]
}, adj) {
    // do stuff with debit and credit values
}
```

When I try to call the function with an object without the third element in the column data array ( e.g. `createBalance({ ColumnData: [foo, {value:20}]} , bar)` ), I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

Am I trying to use the defaults incorrectly here? I feel like this site led me to believe this method would work: http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html (section 1.6).

All that said, I do have a simple workaround. I rewrote the function to be:

```
createBalance(
{
    ColumnData: [, debit = {value:0}, credit = {value:0}]
}, adj) {
    debit = debit.value;
    credit = credit.value;
    // carry on as before...
}
```

To summarize my question, what is wrong with my initial attempt? Is this something Babeljs doesn't support currently, or am I misunderstanding defaults (or destructuring)?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I can [reproduce with this](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=function%20createBalance(%5B%7Bvalue%3A%20debit%3D1%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%5D%2C%20ds)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(debit)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AcreateBalance(%5B%5D)), but ominously works when you a) omit the second parameter b) omit the inner default value for the property

Comment: I filed a bug [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1908).

Comment: Submitted [a PR to fix this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/1915).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, @Bergi and @loganfsmyth! I was pretty sure I was doing things right!